# Eclipse JavaFX can't find out how to set different links to the same button

Tags: eclipse, javafx, fxml, getter-setter, efxclipse

I've been trying to set different Data for each of my entries to one of my fxml's in scenebuilder that I made to look like a "tile/widget" that goes into the main menu through FXMLLoader and i have made that happen with any media I needed except redirecting to different websites. Now i added a button to my fxml which I needs to have different entry for each of the "tiles" i want to create on my main menu screen. I used this method to set my data till now but i needed a method to activate the button going to different websites depending on what i add to the main controller.

```
public class HotelController {

    @FXML
    private ImageView img;

    @FXML
    private Label startingprice;

    @FXML
    private Label hotelname;

    @FXML
    private Button hotelsURL;


    public void setData(Hotel hotel){
        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(hotel.getImgSrc()));
        img.setImage(image);
        hotelname.setText(hotel.getName());
        //days.setText(hotel.getNbDays()+"Days");
        startingprice.setText(hotel.getPrice()+"€ a night");
        hotelsURL.setText(hotel.getLink());
    }


    @FXML
    void hotelURLpressed(ActionEvent event){
        Desktop browser = Desktop.getDesktop();
        try{
            browser.browse(new URI(hotel.getLink()));
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{}
    }
}
```

The above code is the code I use in the controller of the tiles which has the problem in the second snippet i added at `browser.browse(new URI(hotel.getLink()));`. I cannot find a way other than making the whole thing static at the "scene.java" file but then the links do not change.
The code i use to change the links for every entry is:

```
private List<Hotel> getHotels() {
    List<Hotel> ls = new ArrayList<>();

    Hotel hotel = new Hotel();
    hotel.setName("Hotel1");
    hotel.setImgSrc("/img/image1.jpg");
    hotel.setPrice(36);
    hotel.setLink("www.link1.com");
    //hotel.setNbDays(1);
    ls.add(hotel);

    hotel = new Hotel();
    hotel.setName("Hotel2");
    hotel.setImgSrc("/img/image2.jpg");
    hotel.setPrice(45);
    hotel.setLink("www.link2.com");
    ls.add(hotel);

    return ls ;
}
```

Also the code for the getters and setters at my "scene.java" is

```
package scenes;

public class Hotel {
    private String name;
    private String imgSrc;
    private int price;
    private String link;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImgSrc() {
        return imgSrc;
    }
    public void setImgSrc(String imgSrc) {
        this.imgSrc = imgSrc;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }
    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a `hotel` instance variable in the controller, and assign it in the `setData(...)` method, so it can be accessed in the event handler:

```
public class HotelController {

    // reference to Hotel that is displayed:

    private Hotel hotel ;

    @FXML
    private ImageView img;
    
    @FXML
    private Label startingprice;
    
    @FXML
    private Label hotelname;
    
    @FXML
    private Button hotelsURL;


    public void setData(Hotel hotel){

        // save Hotel reference:
        this.hotel = hotel ;

        Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(hotel.getImgSrc()));
        img.setImage(image);
        hotelname.setText(hotel.getName());
        //days.setText(hotel.getNbDays()+"Days");
        startingprice.setText(hotel.getPrice()+"€ a night");
        hotelsURL.setText(hotel.getLink());
    }

    @FXML
    void hotelURLpressed(ActionEvent event){
        Desktop browser = Desktop.getDesktop();
        try{
            browser.browse(new URI(hotel.getLink()));
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 

}
```